# Objective C - Generate an array of time objects with an interval of X mins?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, time, nsdate

I would like to create an array of time objects in 24-hour clock which have an interval of X mins between each one; and should validate as NSDate/NSTime objects.

ie: Generated output

`00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, etc`

I'd like the time objects to be validatable against NSDates.

I'm thinking that we have an array of NSDates, but I'm not sure how to make each one X minutes away from the previous one without it going over 24 hrs.

Many thanks

---

Edit: First attempt

Okay, I've made an attempt at this given the answer below

```
      NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        components.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        components.hour =  11;
        components.minute = 0;
        components.second = 0;

        NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];


        NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [NSDateFormatter vic_timeFormatter];
        [timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

        for (int i=1; i<48; i++) {

            NSUInteger seconds = (1800 * i);
            NSDate *newDate= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:seconds sinceDate:date];
            NSLog(@"newDate = %@", newDate);
            NSString *formatted = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
            NSLog(@"Formatted = %@", formatted);
        }

        timeFormatter=nil;
```

I chose 48 as 1800 occurs 48 times in a 24-hour clock

Except that in my logs, it always ends around 10:30

Ideally I'd like it to run until 11:30PM or 12:00PM; regardless of when the time starts from (in the above scenario it starts at 11AM)

Log returns below;

```
newDate = 2015-02-20 11:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 11:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-20 12:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 12:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 12:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 12:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 13:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 1:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 13:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 1:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 14:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 2:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 14:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 2:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 15:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 3:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 15:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 3:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 16:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 4:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 16:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 4:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 17:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 5:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 17:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 5:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 18:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 6:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 18:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 6:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 19:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 7:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 19:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 7:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 20:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 8:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 20:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 8:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 21:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 9:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 21:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 9:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 22:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 10:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 22:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 10:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 23:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 11:00 PM
newDate = 2015-02-20 23:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 11:30 PM
newDate = 2015-02-21 00:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 12:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 00:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 12:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 01:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 1:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 01:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 1:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 02:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 2:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 02:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 2:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 03:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 3:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 03:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 3:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 04:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 4:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 04:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 4:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 05:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 5:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 05:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 5:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 06:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 6:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 06:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 6:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 07:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 7:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 07:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 7:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 08:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 8:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 08:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 8:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 09:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 9:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 09:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 9:30 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 10:00:00 +0000
Formatted = 10:00 AM
newDate = 2015-02-21 10:30:00 +0000
Formatted = 10:30 AM
```

Comment: Update your for loop to be i < 50 and it should do the full 24 hours

Comment: Many thanks.  But sometimes it runs over to the next day; rather I think it probably should not do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the dateWithTimeInterval method. Example

```
NSDate *newDate= [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1800 sinceDate:yourDate];
```

Comment: This was good and helpful; I believe I need to fire the 1800 at least 48 times for 48 times